# What is the source for the Kallah's circling the Chasan 7 times?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, marriage, wedding

What is the source for a Kallah (bride) to circle her Chasan (bridegroom) seven times at their wedding?

Comment: yehoshua and yericho

Comment: @joshwaxman: what is the connection of yehoshua and yericho with a kallah's circling?

Comment: #1, a joke; #2, yehoshua married rachav and here circled her; #3 break down boundaries between the chasan and kallah. really, #1

Comment: I'd like to note that this is not a universal practice, although almost all Ashkenazim do it.

Answer (score 10):

The Kallah encircles the Chosson seven times under the chuppah, from the verse "A woman shall go around a man." (Jeremiah 31:22). The act also recalls the seven times Tefillin straps are wrapped around the arm. Just as a man binds himself in love of Hashem, so is his bond in love to the Bride. The number seven represents the completion of the seven day process in which earth was created. During these seven days, the earth revolved on its axis seven times. Since marriage reenacts the creative process, the Kallah's encirclement symbolizes the repetition of these seven rotations. The Chosson is compared to a king. Just as the king is encircled by his legion, the groom is to be encircled by his bridal entourage.

Summarized from: [Jewish Wedding Traditions](http://www.jewishweddingtraditions.org/chassidic-wedding)

Comment: Any sources from Sefarim?

Comment: @Gershon Gold: I'm surprised that there isn't any connection to Israel's circling of Jericho (Josh. 6:1-27). I always considered that an act of possession, just as Abraham was commanded to walk the length and width of the Land (Gen. 13:17). See also Ps. 48:12. So when the bride circles, she stakes her claim. Also, metaphorically, the wall of negiah that has kept the couple apart collapses, just as the walls of Jericho did. I'm stil looking for a published source for that thought, although Rabbi Dr. Barry Fruendel told me he has used the analogy at weddings.

Comment: That verse from Jeremiah 31:22 is not the peshat. Which sefarim quote that as a source?

Comment: @Yaabim R Aryeh Kaplan cites Tikkuney Zohar 6, 23a - see also [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/123763/11501)

Answer (score 5):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 147:5 says 7 times.

https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.147.5

Answer (score 2):

**[Rav Eliezer Melamed, *Peninei Halacha*, Family 5:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Family.5.13.1-5)**

> למנהג אשכנז, לאחר שהכלה נכנסת לחופה, יחד עם השושבינות היא מקיפה את
> החתן שבע פעמים, ולאחר מכן מתייצבת בצד ימינו. שבע הקפות נועדו לבטא
> שהנישואין הם לשם שמיים, וכנגד זה שהקב"ה מתגלה בשבעה רקיעים, הכלה מקיפה
> את החתן שבע פעמים.
>
> הטעם העמוק הוא, שבכל מקום שעושים הקפות רומזים למדרגה גדולה וגבוהה
> מהבנתנו. זה ההבדל בין מדרגת הקו למדרגת העיגול. לקו ישר יש התחלה ויש
> סוף, מה שמבטא את יכולתנו להתבונן באופן שיטתי בכל רעיון קווי, שיש בו
> הנחה ראשונה שממנה משתלשלת עוד הנחה עד להנחה המסכמת. אבל למעגל אין
> התחלה ואין סוף, לרמוז שמדובר ברעיון אין סופי שאיננו יכולים לקלוט את
> כולו, אבל הוא משפיע עלינו השפעה עצומה, שכן הוא מקיף את כל תודעתנו
> ומעניק לה השראה. הדיבור נרמז בקו, ומה שמעבר לדיבור נרמז בעיגול. לכן
> כאשר מסיימים את התורה בשמחת-תורה נוהגים לערוך הקפות, לרמוז שלאחר כל מה
> שזכינו ללמוד ולהבין עדיין לא הגענו לקלוט מעט מזעיר מהחכמה האלוקית
> שבתורה, אבל כיוון שזכינו לעסוק בה היא מקיפה אותנו ואנו זוכים לקבל ממנה
> השראה שמכוונת את מחשבותינו ומרוממת את דרכנו. וכך גם בעת החתונה,
> ההתרגשות כל כך גדולה, והמשמעות של הנישואין כל כך עמוקה ונשגבה, עד שגם
> כל הברכות והמילים שאומרים בחתונה אינן יכולות לבטא את גודל משמעותה,
> ולשם כך עורכים הקפות כדי לבטא את מה שמעל ומעבר למילים ולקבל ממנו
> השראה.
>
> עורכים שבע הקפות, מפני שמספר שבע הוא המספר השלם שמופיע בעולם הזה, שהרי
> העולם נברא בשבעה ימים. ולכן בסיום התורה מקיימים שבע הקפות, לבטא שהתורה
> מאירה את כל שבע הבחינות שבעולם הזה. וכן שבע ההקפות של הכלה מבטאות את
> השראת הקדושה של החתונה על כל שבע הבחינות שבחיים.
>
> והכלה מקיפה את החתן כדי לבטא מצד אחד את כמיהתה אליו, ומאידך, לרמוז שמן
> הצד הפנימי מדרגתה של האשה גבוהה משל האיש, ועל כן בה מתבטא המעגל וההיקף
> שרומז אל מה שמעבר להשגה. ואילו החתן הוא בבחינת הקו, ולכן הוא זה שעושה
> את הדברים הגלויים, הוא אומר את נוסח הקידושין והוא מקנה לכלה את טבעת
> הקידושין (עי' לעיל ד, ט-יג).

Answer (score 2):

R Aryeh Kaplan in his book [Made in heaven](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0940118114/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_KXMB30TB8E2NCW5SNEV3) (pp. 158ff) writes additional reasons in addition to those listed in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5359/11501)

- one of the symbolisms of the wedding ring is that of the aura of protection that the husband gives to the wife. However in the Messianic era, man and woman will be equal, and the wife will also be able to protect her husband. **The woman walks around the man to indicate their hope that the Messianic era will become a full reality**
- the bride walking around the groom also indicates that she is binding him with certain obligations. A groom has three Torah obligations: food, clothing, and conjugal relations. In places where the bride walks around the groom three times, the circuits, represent these three obligations. **The custom of her making seven circuits may indicate the seven additional obligations that were legislated by the rabbis** (ketuba, medical expenses, ransom, burial expenses, support through his estate after his death, support her other children, have her sons inherit her ketuba)
- as soon as the groom marries the bride, **seven of her relatives become forbidden to him**
- the bride is praying that **the merit of the seven prophetesses and the seven shepherds of Israel protect her marriage and ensure its success**