# Source for the bride's circling the groom

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, wedding

I understand that there are ways of deriving a scriptural basis for the tradition of circling one's groom [three times](http://judaism.about.com/od/weddings/ss/wedding_how_5.htm) or [seven times](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/what-is-the-source-of-the-kallah-circling-the-chasan-7-times), etc - but what is the earliest (written) source for this being a custom?

Comment: Is this not an exact duplicate of the question you link to merely because you're seeking a source for circling three *or* seven times whereas the other question seeks a source for circling seven times only?

Comment: The question I linked to asked for the source only; I wanted the earliest written reference to it. Had the answer that I'd been given already been put there as well, I wouldn't have asked it. Now that @sam has answered it in both places, should I take my question down?

Comment: Since Sam has added the same answer in both places and, here, doesn't actually show that it's the *earliest* source (what this this question asks) but you accepted it anyway, I'm inclined to mark as a duplicate.  Other thoughts?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, sounds good, except for the three vs. seven thing, which I don't know what to do with.

Comment: @msh210, close this and if Shimon wants to ask separately about sources for three he can?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, good idea; done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 147:5 says 7 times.

http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur147.html

Comment: I doubt that's the earliest source, but that will help me find it. Thanks!

Comment: Nope - it actually **might** be the oldest textual reference!